# Plotting of list data using pyscript

Tags: javascript, custom-list, python

I have SharePoint 2013 and 2016 environments that I like to add some plots for some custom lists (webapp part) of SharePoint.

I thought of using [pyscript](https://anaconda.cloud/pyscript-python-in-the-browser) but I couldn't go too much further as I can't access or move/copy list data to the Python script side.

What should be the suggested way to do this, if there is a tutorial or docs already I couldn't find them yet. May be a MWE available?